Compute the difference between the Christoffel symbols compatible with two different metric tensors
Imagine I have two metric tensors $g_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\hat{g}_{\alpha\beta}$ on the same manifold M and two metric-compatible, torsion free Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}$
$$\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\rho}\big(\partial_\alpha g_{\rho\beta}+\partial_\beta g_{\alpha \rho}-\partial_\rho g_{\alpha \beta})$$
and $\hat{\Gamma}^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ defined just as $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ but using $\hat{g}$ instead of $g$. I'm interested in the difference between the Christoffel symbols, namely, the tensor
$$ C^\mu_{\alpha\beta}=\hat{\Gamma}^\mu_{\alpha\beta} -\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$$
Is there an expression for such an object? Of course I know it can be simply written as
$$C^\mu_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{g}^{\mu\rho}\big(\partial_\alpha \hat{g}_{\rho\beta}+\partial_\beta \hat{g}_{\alpha \rho}-\partial_\rho \hat{g}_{\alpha \beta})-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\rho}\big(\partial_\alpha g_{\rho\beta}+\partial_\beta g_{\alpha \rho}-\partial_\rho g_{\alpha \beta})$$
but I wonder if there's a simpler expression, I imagine that it could be something involving $\hat{\nabla}_\mu g_{\alpha\beta}$ or cross terms like that where you derive one metric using the covariant derivative compatible with the other metric. Does anyone know about this?
Also, I know that when $\hat{g}=g+h$ with $h$ a small perturbation, there are expressions for the difference of Christoffel symbols to leading order. I'm wondering if there's an expression for this in the nonperturbative case. I'd be happy with the sum of a bunch of perturbative terms too I guess.

Why would the difference be a tensor? If you have two different metric tensors you are comparing two different manifolds. The result of taking the difference is almost certainly not a tensor.

@VincentThacker not true. First, we can definitely consider different metrics on the same manifold. Second, the difference between any two linear connections on any vector bundle $(E,\pi,M)$ is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued 1-form, or what amounts to the same thing, a bilinear bundle morphism $TM\oplus E\to E$; this in the special case of $E=TM$ simply means the difference is a $(1,2)$-tensor field on $M$, exactly as OP said (at the level of coordinates, the transformation law for Christoffel symbols has an ‘ugly extra term’ but this cancels out when taking the difference).

@peek-a-boo Which is why I asked for that clarification, because OP simply talks about "two metric tensors". The expression $\tilde{\Gamma}^\mu_{\alpha\beta}-\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ only makes sense when the underlying smooth manifold is the same and is indeed a tensor in that case.

OP, take a look at this MSE answer.

Hi! Yes! The underlying manifold should be the same! I’ll modify the question

The answer in Mathematics is what I was looking for! Thanks!

I think Wald's book gives the expression you want
